# Como passar parâmetros por providers AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-providers

Eu tenho as rotas padrão do site em um `constant`:

```
app.constant('defaultRoutes', {
    home: {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    },
   [...demais rotas....]
});
```

Estou chamando este `constant` neste `provider`

```
app.provider("routeConfig", function (defaultRoutes,$httpProvider) {
    [... logica aqui...]
    this.$get = defaultRoutes;
});
```

Este `provider` será instanciado no `app.config()`

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,routeConfigProvider) {
    [...lógica para configurar as rotas...]
})
```

Até ai está funcionando ok, mas a dúvida é: como poderia ser feito uma forma de dar a opção de quem usar a classe, **sobrescrever** os valores default sem alterar o `constant`?

Já tentei substituir `constant` por `value` mas este só pode ser usado depois da inicialização de `app.config()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$logProvider', function ($routeProvider, $logProvider) {

// Configuração de rotas
$routeProvider
    .when('/page/:ID', {
        templateUrl: 'App/Views/page.html',
        controller: 'Controller'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

Essa é a forma que eu utilizo para passar o `ID` como parâmetro nas minhas rotas, utilizando `angular-route.js`, que é chamado na inicialização do módulo:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
```

Comment: Na verdade não é este o caso, eu estou usando `Angular-Ui-Router` para fazer o controle de rotas, isso explica meu app.config recebendo `($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider..`

A questão é, ele está funcionando assim, mas de modo estático. Preciso deixar flexivel para que o `defaultRoutes` possa ser sobreescrito

Comment: Mas quando vc utiliza app.constant, está informando uma variável ou função fixa ou seja imutável que é instanciada antes mesmo do carregamento dos métodos. Dessa forma não há como ser flexível.

Comment: Justamente essa a pergunta: "O que eu poderia usar pra ser flexivel?"

Comment: Talvez o link possa te ajudar: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/06/decorating-angularjs-services.aspx